# Direction in Limit

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

Let's consider the limit

```
Limit[(x^2 + y^2)^2 Log[-(x^2 + y^2)], {x, y} -> {0, 0}]
(* 0 *)
```

Why if Mathematica takes the limit with a specific direction, eg.

```
Limit[(x^2 + y^2)^2 Log[-(x^2 + y^2)], {x, y} -> {0, 0}, Direction->-1]
```

doesn't give the same solution as before?

Comment: `Limit[(x^2 + y^2)^2 Log[-(x^2 + y^2)], Thread[{x, y} -> {0, 0}], 
 Direction -> -1]` does give `0`.

Comment: yes, but the two limits, the one with {x, y} -> {0, 0} and the one with {x -> 0, y -> 0}, should coincide, also if, in general, they don't.

Comment: Giancarlo, I agree.  It seems that the  form `{x, y} -> {0, 0}`  is a new feature (it does not work in version 9) . It is possibly an oversight that `{x, y} -> {0, 0} ` does not work when the option `Direction` is used.

Comment: I would report this to Wolfram Support.  `Limit` got an overhaul recently. Multivariate limits are also a new feature (11.2 I think).  It may still be a bit rough around the edges.

Comment: It is fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

Up to http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Limit.html , the correct syntax is

```
Limit[f[x, y], {x, y} -> {0, 0}, Direction -> {Reals, "FromBelow"}]
```

Comment: If in your code I substitute f[x,y] with my function, it doesn't give a numbers as well. Moreover from http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Direction «Approaching the origin from the first quadrant [...] Direction -> "FromAbove" [...] Equivalently: [...] Direction -> {"FromAbove", "FromAbove"}»

Comment: That's a new syntax they added fairly recently, most likely because people found the `+1`/`-1` specification confusing. `-1` is actually `"FromAbove"`.

Comment: @user64494: In version 11.2, you syntax with option `Direction -> {Reals, "FromBelow"}` returns unevaluated (after defining `f[x_, y_]`, of course).